# Create a 3d box model in android using ARCore

Tags: android, arcore

Do anyone know how to draw a 3d box model with Arcore and place it in a vertical plane.

Answer (score 0):

Take Google's helloAR.java sample code and replace andy.obj with something like this square, but with 6 sides:
v 0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v 2.000000 2.000000 0.000000
vt 0.0 0.0
vt 1.0 0.0
vt 1.0 1.0
vt 1.0 1.0
vn 0.0 1.0 0.0
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1

Comment: Is there any option we can dynamically set the height, width, and depth of the box

Comment: Have not found any way to do that, but it says its possible in the source code Mesh.java that: "The data in the given {@link IndexBuffer} and {@link VertexBuffer}s does not need to be finalized; they may be freely changed throughout the lifetime of a {@link Mesh} using their respective {@code set()} methods." so please let me know if you ever figure it out...

Comment: Before you waste too much time on this, I should mention that I think what the above says is leftover from years ago when it was still possible to do that...